# pip install chompjs in scrapy virtual environment under anaconda showing errors

Tags: python, scrapy, anaconda

chompjs pip install throwing the following errors:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for chompjs

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: The downloaded project doesn't include a Windows binary. So `pip` tries to compile it from source. But for that it needs a C compiler. The message says you don't have it installed.

Comment: Can you help me how to install chompjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem even if I had Build Tools installed. This [installer](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/bacf7555-1a20-4bf4-ae4d-1003bbc25da8/f3a7e2868c203490a4095231e20e628bf661b7469f2d53626f3fbbdfc161d471/vs_BuildTools.exe)  and video helps me: [[SOLVED] Unable to install Visual C++ build tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_R3tXSq0KI)

Comment: Thanks. I 've installed Build Tools successfully and now pip command for chompjs has worked.